# Average Distinct Values in a single column in Power Pivot

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I have a column in PowerPivot that basically goes:

1
1
2
3
4
3
5
4

If I =AVERAGE([Column]), it's going to average all 8 values in the sample column.  I just need the average of the distinct values (i.e., in the example above I want the average of (1,2,3,4,5).

Any thoughts on how to go about doing this?  I tried a combination of =(DISTINCT(AVERAGE)) but it gives a formula error.

Thanks!!

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

There must be a cleaner way of doing this but here is one method which uses a measure to get the sum of the values divided by the number of times it appears (to basically give the original value) then uses an iterative function to do it for each unique value.

Apologies for the uninspired measure names:

```
[m1] = SUM(table1[theValue]) / COUNTROWS(Table1)
[m2] = AVERAGEX(VALUES(Tables1[theValue]), [m1])
```

Assuming your table is caled table1 and the column is called theValue